# Convert array in to specific format recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have one array that contains hierarchical data, i wan to convert it to hierarchy but in different format. I tried to use recursive method but its not giving proper data

Below is my code what i tried to implement

```
static convertConfigJson(data, finalResults = []) {

        const configData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

        return configData.map((item) => {
            const { name, type, value, path } = item;
            let children = {}
            if (type === 'Object') {
              children = this.convertConfigJson(value, finalResults);
            } else {

            finalResults.push({
                id: name,
                name: name,
                children: children
            })
            }




            console.log('>>>>>>>>>', finalResults)

            return finalResults;
          });   
    }
```

Below is JSON array that i am getting from API

```
[
        {
            "name": "info",
            "type": "Object",
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "app",
                    "type": "Object",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "path": "info.app",
                            "name": "encoding",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "@project.build.sourceEncoding@"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "java",
                            "type": "Object",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "path": "info.app.java",
                                    "name": "source",
                                    "type": "TEXT",
                                    "value": "@java.version@"
                                },
                                {
                                    "path": "info.app.java",
                                    "name": "target",
                                    "type": "TEXT",
                                    "value": "java.version@"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to convert above array in below format i.e. change value array to children

```
[
    {
        "name": "info",
        "type": "Object",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "app",
                "type": "Object",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "path": "info.app",
                        "name": "encoding",
                        "type": "TEXT",
                        "value": "@project.build.sourceEncoding@"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "java",
                        "type": "Object",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "path": "info.app.java",
                                "name": "source",
                                "type": "TEXT",
                                "value": "@java.version@"
                            },
                            {
                                "path": "info.app.java",
                                "name": "target",
                                "type": "TEXT",
                                "value": "java.version@"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple recursive walk on all elements in children property.  set .value to .children and delete .value

```js
walk = node => {
  if(!node.value || typeof node.value!=='object') return
  node.children = node.value
  delete node.value
  node.children.forEach(walk)
}

data.forEach(walk)

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script>
data=[
        {
            "name": "info",
            "type": "Object",
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "app",
                    "type": "Object",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "path": "info.app",
                            "name": "encoding",
                            "type": "TEXT",
                            "value": "@project.build.sourceEncoding@"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "java",
                            "type": "Object",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "path": "info.app.java",
                                    "name": "source",
                                    "type": "TEXT",
                                    "value": "@java.version@"
                                },
                                {
                                    "path": "info.app.java",
                                    "name": "target",
                                    "type": "TEXT",
                                    "value": "java.version@"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
</script>
```

Comment: modern browsers, difference is mostly negligible: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9cTaYI95Zc&feature=youtu.be&t=951  https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#avoid-creating-holes

Comment: @Disfigure, what will be gained on 10 000 elements?

Comment: @Disfigure: how much performance boost do you think is worth the extra code complexity?  This is a nice simple solution.

Comment: @user120242 I agree, you said "mostly negligible" so the difference exists :)

Comment: right, but as you can see in the article on V8 as an example, forEach has native level optimizations.   In some cases, depending on what you are doing, it can actually be faster

Comment: Note that (in recent Chrome at least) there is no performance difference between the code above and the  simplest conversion of `forEach` to `for`: https://jsbench.me/3okbc5emwq/1.  Each run seems to give a different winner, with only a few percent difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is similar to the answer from user120242, but it does not mutate your input structure, creating a new one instead:

```js
const transform = ({value, ...rest}) => 
  Array .isArray (value)
    ? {...rest, children: value .map (transform)}
    : {...rest, value}

const data = [{name: "info", type: "Object", value: [{name: "app", type: "Object", value: [{path: "info.app", name: "encoding", type: "TEXT", value: "@project.build.sourceEncoding@"}, {name: "java", type: "Object", value: [{path: "info.app.java", name: "source", type: "TEXT", value: "@java.version@"}, {path: "info.app.java", name: "target", type: "TEXT", value: "java.version@"}]}]}]}]

console .log (data .map (transform))
```

### Update

Borrowing a technique [from sivako](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62329184), we can simplify this nicely:

```js
const transform = ({value, ...rest}) => ({
  ... rest, 
  ... (Array .isArray (value) ? {children: value .map (transform)} : {value})
})

const data = [{name: "info", type: "Object", value: [{name: "app", type: "Object", value: [{path: "info.app", name: "encoding", type: "TEXT", value: "@project.build.sourceEncoding@"}, {name: "java", type: "Object", value: [{path: "info.app.java", name: "source", type: "TEXT", value: "@java.version@"}, {path: "info.app.java", name: "target", type: "TEXT", value: "java.version@"}]}]}]}]

console .log (data .map (transform))
```

Answer (score 1):

write `transform` method, When ever object has the "value" type is Array then call the `transform` recursively.

```js
const transform = ({ value, ...rest }) => {
  const item = { ...rest };
  Array.isArray(value)
    ? (item["children"] = value.map(transform))
    : (item["value"] = value);
  return item;
};

// Update: Based on @user120242 suggestion, creating another object is not required and using `Object.assign` will simplify.

const transform2 = ({ value, ...rest }) =>
  Object.assign(
    rest,
    Array.isArray(value) ? { children: value.map(transform2) } : { value }
  );

const items = [
  {
    name: "info",
    type: "Object",
    value: [
      {
        name: "app",
        type: "Object",
        value: [
          {
            path: "info.app",
            name: "encoding",
            type: "TEXT",
            value: "@project.build.sourceEncoding@",
          },
          {
            name: "java",
            type: "Object",
            value: [
              {
                path: "info.app.java",
                name: "source",
                type: "TEXT",
                value: "@java.version@",
              },
              {
                path: "info.app.java",
                name: "target",
                type: "TEXT",
                value: "java.version@",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const output = items.map(transform);
console.log(output);

console.log(items.map(transform2));
```

Comment: @ScottSauyet, Yeah, Did not see your answer before posting. even came up with same method name `transform` :)

Comment: @user120242, Agree, creating new clone is unnecessary.  should have updated `rest ` itself. Just updated answer with alternate way using the `Object.assign`. Thank you.

Comment: That updated version is very nice!  I think I'll add an update to mine to match.

Answer (score 0):

An easiest way is just replace all `"value": [` to `"children": [` after stringify

```
function convertConfigJson(data) {
  const configData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"value":\[/g, '"children":['));
  return configData
}
```

also you can go one by one through all keys of nested object, and replace value keys with array in value to children

Comment: This solution has a drawback, that it will also replace words "value" if they are in value of any key of this object.

Comment: @matvs, no, because square brackets are included...for ts structure it is okay but as universal solution it should not be used as this, i just suggested the most simple way in sense of code. But solution with loop over all elements is more reasonable of course

Comment: Thanks @DmitryReutov, i need a way with recursive method call, i wight need to update other properties or object structure